# How do I write sbit in C#

Tags: c#, c

I am porting c code of a firmware to c# and not sure how this keyword

```
"sbit"
```

can be written in c#. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, it's not a standard C keyword, that's for sure. Could you post a larger part of the code than just one word?

Comment: Could you provide an example of its usage?  Some 'C' firmware compilers allow various keyword extensions for low-level operations like setting an I/O bit.  My guess would be that this sets a built-in output bit on the microcontroller.

Comment: @GSerg - How else can you tell the positive ones from the negative ones?

Comment: It's probably a `typedef` or a `#define` in the source code.

Comment: Is it related to this http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/c51/c51_le_sbit.htm.  If so i don't think there is a c# equivalent it is too low level

Comment: Leaving jokes aside, I find the very concept of porting firmware to c# disturbing. It's ARM assembler, isn't it? [Link 1](http://www.keil.com/support/docs/2811.htm). [Link 2](http://www.keil.com/support/docs/1441.htm).

Comment: @GSerg: Smells like a nullable bool ;p

Comment: In our company they already have decided to port things to gui, so software can do more stuffs.

Comment: Here is a snippet of code where I found the usage:

    // Port bits assigned to Amba Peripheral Bus (APB)
    // P0^7..P0^0               // output=reg_addr, input=data_in (APB prdata)
       sbit APB_SEL = P1^7;     // select a bus transaction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[link](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/c51/c51_le_sbit.htm) @Ben Robinson,

"(...)With typical 8051 applications, it is often necessary to access individual bits within an SFR. The sbit type provides access to bit-addressable SFRs and other bit-addressable objects. For example:

```
sbit EA = 0xAF;
```

This declaration defines EA as the SFR bit at address 0xAF. On the 8051, this is the enable all bit in the interrupt enable register.(...)".

```
sbit name = sfr-address ^ bit-position;
```

This too low level, you might try to use c++.net, for that matter. C# is a high level language, using pointers can be a little tricky, it can be done, but escapes from c# real intent.
You could use c++.net made functions, as the final code of both is the same [clr (Common Language Run-Time)], the machine will not note the diference.